# Payment using reward points not showing up on checkout in Magento Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento, reward

I am working on a project in Magento Enterprise Edition and need to use the reward points system in the site. I set up the reward points system in the admin panel and allowed customer with 260 reward points. But when I tried to do the checkout, purchasing product using reward point is not shown.

Normally I heard this will be coming under payment option while doing the checkout. But in my case this is not working. I have enabled the reward points and I think I have entered all the necessary settings. What might I be missing or what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Quick-answer:*** Set TWO Reward Exchange Rates:
**From points to money** and **from money to points**

---

For very long time we tried to resolve this issue. We found that the problem was here:

```
    if (!$helper->getHasRates() || !$helper->isEnabledOnFront()) {
        return false;
    }
```

and $helper->getHasRates() returns false, because:

```
    $hasRates = $rate->fetch(
        $groupId, $websiteId, Enterprise_Reward_Model_Reward_Rate::RATE_EXCHANGE_DIRECTION_TO_CURRENCY
    )->getId() &&
        $rate->reset()->fetch(
            $groupId,
            $websiteId,
            Enterprise_Reward_Model_Reward_Rate::RATE_EXCHANGE_DIRECTION_TO_POINTS
        )->getId();
```

I checking TWO params. Only people from **** could come up with it...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction; I found that the "All Websites" setting for currency was the issue.  After much digging, and logging, I that using my store's website fixed the issue. When using All Websites, the currency exchange rate was not getting passed.

Comment: having same problem, even after setting it up, not having reward points payment option on the checkout, please advise??

Comment: Saurabh Dixit -- also make sure that you aren't using a community theme on an enterprise install - hit that snag as well....

Comment: Thank you so much for such great help. I added Reward Exchange Rates both directions and reward points section appear me at checkout for redeeming.

Comment: Thanks for you solution, This is still issue in ver. 2.3.1